# Question about using sum query in Posgresql

Tags: postgresql, sum

I have an SQL table like this:

**Grocery**

```
grocery_item  |  quantity  |  price  |  total

soap          |     2      |    10   |  20
coffee        |     5      |     4   |  20
```

I have an SQL query like:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM grocery;
```

It gives me 40, which is what I needed. However, if I have a lot of grocery items, I think the querying of the sum will be slower.

My question is, is there a way to improve this for example saving the sum and then if I add some grocery items, it will just add the new item's price to the previous total?

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 But I dont think you need add anything to improve performance of calculate the Total.